# Finding the Sum of a series $\frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1+2}{2!} +\frac{1+2+3}{3!}+...$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I need to find the sum of this series $$\dfrac{1}{1!} + \dfrac{1+2}{2!} + \dfrac{1+2+3}{3!}+\ldots$$ But somehow I am not even convinced this converges. I tried writing it as $\sum \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2(n!)}$. I also tried to rewrite it as a telescoping series. But I seem to be stuck. Some hints on where I am going wrong would help. I am supposed to get the answer as $\dfrac{3e}{2}$.

Comment: **Hint:** $n(n+1)=n(n-1)+2n.$

Comment: If you decompose the sum as fractions you can see that all fractions converges. After you know that it converges you can manipulate it in many ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may write

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{n(n+1)}{2(n!)}&=\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)+2n}{2(n!)}\\\\
> &=\sum_2^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{2(n!)}+\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{2n}{2(n!)}\\\\
> &=\frac12\sum_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\\\\
> &=\frac12\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}+\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\\\\
> &=\frac32e
> \end{align}
> $$

since
$$
\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x, \quad x \in \mathbb{C}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

What I said

$$\sum \frac{n^2+n}{2 n!}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum \frac{n\color{red}{+1-1}}{(n-1)!} +\sum \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+ \sum \frac{1}{(n-2)!} +\sum \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right)$$

And if you know that $\sum \frac{1}{n!}=e$ then...

And you know too algebra of limits, i.e., you know that if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=R$ and $L,R \in \mathbb R$ then $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\to a} f(x) + \lim_{x\to a} g(x)$

I will add some more: you can rearrange terms because all these series have absolute convergence, if they converges, because they are only of positive terms: Cauchy criteria for absolute convergence says that $\sum |a_n| \to L, L\in\mathbb R$ then if the series $\sum a_n$ converges, then it converges *absolutely* and you can rearrange terms and they converges to the same value.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yeah there are quite a few ways to do this. I feel dumb once the answers come along. I hope you dont mind if I accept the earlier answer.

Comment: No problem @Vishesh :). But its important that you know that you CAN manipulate the series or when you cannot. For series of positives terms if they converges then it converges absolutely and you can manipulate the series in many ways cause this.