# Sum of the Series using 'e'

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the sum of the series
$\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1+2}{2!}+\frac{1+2+3}{3!}+.....$ equal to $1+\frac{3e}{2}$.

I don't know how to find sum of this series, please tell me how to solve it?

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364387/finding-the-sum-of-a-series-frac11-frac122-frac1233, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597328/find-the-summation-frac11-frac122-frac1233-cdots, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574776/what-is-the-value-of-the-series – all found quickly using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1!%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%2B2%7D%7B2!%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%2B2%2B3%7D%7B3!%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

So the $n(\ge1)$th term is $$=\dfrac{1+2+\cdots+n}{n!}=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2(n!)}$$

Now $n(n+1)=n(n-1)+2n$

So for $n\ge2,$  $$\dfrac{n(n+1)}{n!}=\dfrac1{(n-2)!}+\dfrac2{(n-1)!}$$

Now recall $e^x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^r}{r!}$